# Нужно чтобы по клику на кнопку выводило данные с инпута в консоль , но почему то они выводятся каждый раз при изменении инпута

Tags: reactjs, react-hook

```
function Text() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  return (
    <div className="white">
      <input type="text" placeholder="enter" onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={console.log(text)}>CLICK</button>

      <div>{text}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что вы передаете в `onClick` результат функции `console.log()`.

Сделайте так: `<button onClick={() => console.log(text)}>CLICK</button>`